# Detect preferred language order in Cordova App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, localization, internationalization

Let's say a developer creates an App that supports `de_DE` and `en_US`.

The developer promotes the App in German and English in the App Stores.

Then there's a user that speaks Spanish and German (in that order) that downloads the app because there's a German translation.

This user has set up his phone with this list of preferred languages:

```
es_ES
de_DE
```

Now, in order to detect the user's language, Cordova suggests to use navigator.language (since the ECMA Internationalization API is available in all the major platforms).

navigator.language will be `es_ES`. At this point, the App does not have any way to find out that the user also speaks German. In that case, the App will probably fall back to `en_US` instead of `de_DE`. Worse than that, the user will get German in the system dialogs but English in the rest of the App.

Does Cordova provide a solid way to get the language that the OS picks from the list that the App supports?

For example, iOS will check `CFBundleLocalizations` and will choose `de_DE` in a non-Cordova App. Android does a similar thing by checking the resource files. But I don't know a way in Cordova to get the final resolution that the OS makes.

Here there's some info how the different OS's choose the App language:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to use [NavigatorLanguage.languages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages) to list all the preferred languages in order

```
 navigator.languages  //["en-US", "zh-CN", "ja-JP"]
```

If you cannot get the language list or only get 1 preferred language, I recommend you get the user [geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) then assign the default language based on geolocation (country). You might need to use an API to convert coordinates to country.

Comment: iOS navigator.languages only has one language in the list even if the user configured her device with multiple languages. Also, navigator.language is always the first language declared by the user and not the match between the App's supported languages and the user's declared languages.

Comment: But of course? What did you expect? You still need to compare and it is an end user "issue". Honestly, just have a selector the first time you run the app to select language. You are seeing this "too big"

Comment: I'd expect to get the best match between what the App provides with what the user prefers. Safari (webkit) only provides one language, BTW (not a list). Anyway I think I found the way to do it. Will update with the final solution.

Comment: @Eric I also get only one language with `navigator.languages` even though iOS shows multiple.